# How to import data from REST API into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I have a REST API that returns a response formatted in JSON, something like this :

```
{
    "Employees" : [
        {
            "userId":"romin",
            "jobTitleName":"Developer",
            "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "userId":"nirani",
            "jobTitleName":"Developer",
            "emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "userId":"tomhan",
            "jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
            "emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any built-in functions that could help in creating a table "Employees" in an SQL Server database from the JSON above ?

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------------+
| UserId |   jobTitleName    |      emailAddress       |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------------+
| romin  | Developer         | romin.k.irani@gmail.com |
| nirani | Developer         | neilrirani@gmail.com    |
| tomhan | Program Directory | tomhanks@gmail.com      |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: have you tried to google for it? There are plenty of different tools available to convert json to sql.

Comment: buil-in function of what? C# or SQL Server?

Comment: @Rahul Both, but C# more likely

Comment: For JSON data in SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: please check this link it can be usefull for you http://www.pauric.blog/How-To-Import-JSON-To-SQL-Server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table-valued function to parse JSON data into rows and columns.

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(max) ='
{
    "Employees" : [
        {
            "userId":"romin",
            "jobTitleName":"Developer",
            "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "userId":"nirani",
            "jobTitleName":"Developer",
            "emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "userId":"tomhan",
            "jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
            "emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
'

SELECT userId,
    jobTitleName,
    emailAddress
FROM OPENJSON(@Json, '$.Employees')
WITH (
    userId VARCHAR(100),
    jobTitleName VARCHAR(100),
    emailAddress VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

first create C# class according to your JSON

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("Employees")]
    public Employee[] Employees { get; set; }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("jobTitleName")]
    public string JobTitleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}



 var JSONObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json); //convert you json in to class object

   var EmpArray=JSONObj["Employees"]; // will give you employee array
```

//Now you can make an iteration over there to insert your data